# Waypoints не работает с jqueryui

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, javascript

Для круговой диаграммы использую waypoints и easypiechart:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    'use strict';
    var $percentChart = $('.monitoring .percent');

    var $barColor = $percentChart.data('bar-color');
    $percentChart.waypoint(function(direction) {
        $percentChart.easyPieChart({
            animate: 1000,
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            lineCap: 'square',
            barColor: $barColor,
            trackColor: '#fff',
            scaleColor: '#f0f0f0', 
            size: 69,
            lineWidth: 5
        }) + 'down';
    }, {
            offset: '85%',
            triggerOnce: true
    });
});
```

При подключении jqueryui диаграммы не отображаются. Возможно как-нибудь решить или придется использовать другой скрипт?

Comment: Можно пример, где не работает? Сейчас всё проверил: http://jsfiddle.net/mzzpd7b4/ ошибок нет.

Comment: сайт на компьютере, у меня ошибок нет, но не работает. jqueryui 1.9.2

Comment: @Arteom  http://jsfiddle.net/mzzpd7b4/2/

Поставил jquery ui 1.9.2

Добавил слайдер, всё работает.

Comment: @lampa, откройте вашу ссылку в Chrome

Comment: @MasterAlex хром, видимо, более придирчив к майм-тайпам. http://jsfiddle.net/mzzpd7b4/3/

Comment: без подключения jqueryui http://arteom.net/demos/waypoints/index.html с подключенным http://arteom.net/demos/waypoints/indexui.html

Answer (score 1):

Отказался от waypoints, скачал последнюю версию [easy-pie-chart](https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart)

Answer (score 0):

Waypoints работает нормально.
Не работает easyPieChart. Канвас с самой диаграммой не отрисовывается.
Попробуйте просто взять другой скрипт для построения диаграмм.